# Dump HTML on a new page

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, rendering, formview

So I have rendered a control in asp.net code, on a button click to HTML.
Now I want to take the HTML and dump it on a new page, so that it can display
all the information within that html page.

Is there any control in asp.net, that I can use in my code behind?
Or how can it be done?

Comment: Do you want to read the html content (rendered by the control), and display them in a new page?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to create a user control.

How to: Create an ASP.NET User Control  - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt3k2fyw.aspx

How to: Include a User Control in an ASP.NET Web Page  - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbz9etab.aspx

Comment: Please don't post old links.

Comment: Ok. How was I supposed to know they were old when they came up in Google? This is the result I received when I searched for "ascx example" - How to: Create an ASP.NET User Control - MSDN - Microsoft
msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26db8ysc(v=vs.85).aspx‎. It was number 2 as a result.

Comment: The fact that the version number on the page says .NET 3.0.

Comment: Also, try to remove the stuff in parentheses from the URL and see if you can still find the page. That will generally allow you to post a link which stays up to date with .NET versions.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply do it using Java script, visit the following link for reference:
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=76